# bash: while read loop - stop if there is variable sshpass

Tags: bash, while-loop

i have a problem with my bash script. I read line by line the variable lvm_path_exec, that works. I confirmed it with echo "lvmpath".
But as soon as i place a sshpass command into the while statement the script only process the first line which got grepped.

If there is no sshpass command all lines of lvmpath_exec get processed.

Do you see the error?

```
lvmpath_exec=$(sshpass -p "${password[$i]}"  ssh ${user[$i]}@${ip[$i]} -p ${port[$i]}  lvdisplay | grep datatest -A 3 | grep Path | awk '{ print $3 }') 

echo "$lvmpath_exec" | while read lvmpath
do
lvmname=datatest
snap=_snapshot
snapname=$lvmname$snap

lvcreate=$(sshpass -p "${password[$i]}"  ssh ${user[$i]}@${ip[$i]} -p ${port[$i]}  lvcreate -L20G -s -n $snapname $lvmpath)

snap_path=$(sshpass -p "${password[$i]}"  ssh ${user[$i]}@${ip[$i]} -p ${port[$i]}  lvdisplay | grep $snapname -A 3 | grep Path | awk '{ print $3 }')

transfer=$(sshpass -p "${password[$i]}"  ssh ${user[$i]}@${ip[$i]} -p ${port[$i]} "dd if=$snap_path | gzip -c" > /tmp/$snapname)

delsnap=$(sshpass -p "${password[$i]}"  ssh ${user[$i]}@${ip[$i]} -p ${port[$i]} lvremove -f $snap_path)

done
```

**UPDATE**

I fixed it:
replace

```
echo "$lvmpath_exec" | while read lvmpath
```

with

```
for lvmpath in $lvmpath_exec
```

But shouldnt it work with while read too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sshpass` works by manipulating `stdin` to fool `ssh` into thinking it is getting the password from an interactive user. When you use a `... | while` style loop, the loop iterates for every line coming from `stdin`, which `sshpass` wipes out after the first call, that's why only the first line gets executed. The `for` loop doesn't use `stdin`, that's why it doesn't have this problem.

As `man sshpass` explains, this tool is inherently insecure and you should really be using public key authentication instead. Also keep in mind that it has other ways of passing the password, using the `-p` flag is the least safe method of all, and any other method would be safer, for example the `-e` flag seems trivially easy. I know you might insist you have a legitimate use case, but this is so important I'm just gonna quote from the man page:

> ```
>    First  and  foremost, users of sshpass should realize that ssh's insis‐
>    tance on only getting the password interactively is not without reason.
>    It  is close to impossible to securely store the password, and users of
>    sshpass should consider whether ssh's public  key  authentication  pro‐
>    vides  the  same  end-user  experience, while involving less hassle and
>    being more secure.
>
>    The -p option should be considered the least secure of all of sshpass's
>    options.   All  system  users  can see the password in the command line
>    with a simple "ps" command. Sshpass makes a minimal attempt to hide the
>    password,  but such attempts are doomed to create race conditions with‐
>    out actually solving the problem. Users of sshpass  are  encouraged  to
>    use  one  of  the other password passing techniques, which are all more
>    secure.
> ```

Comment: Thanks. I know about security problems, but it doesnt affect me.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this..have not tried though

```
export SSHPASS=password[$i]
sshpass -e ssh -oBatchMode=no user[$i]@{ip[$i]} ..
```

Comment: I fixed it now. I didnt tested this, but i dont think this it would have fixed it. Thanks for your answer.